# Initiating Solver without the Mouse

Tags: excel, solver, vba

Without the mouse, I can show the `Format Cells` dialog box by touching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

How can I show the `Solver Parameters` dialog without using the mouse ??

[image]

Comment: I hate using mouses / mice / meeces, so I usually use keyboard shortcuts.  But I tend to still use the pre-2007 keystrokes, so I had to actually find the answer the hard way by pressing Alt, then seeing what tips it showed against each command.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - LOL - good lateral-thinking response!  (Not sure whether it's quite the answer that the OP was looking for, but it gave me a chuckle anyway.)

Comment: @YowE3K I agree with you 100% ! ................additionally your approach can also be implemented in *VBA* with `SendKeys`

Comment: SendKeys will undoubtedly work, but I wouldn't guarantee it on anything other than a personal-use application.  (Different users will almost certainly require different key-strokes.)

Comment: @YowE3K  I agree again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my copy of Excel, you could use Alt-A (to get to the Data menu) and then Y2 to get to Solver. (The "Y2" part will almost certainly be dependent on what other addins are enabled.)